# I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out where I am going wrong

Tags: c++, arrays

here is the instructions for code I am trying to write:

Consider the testPIN function used in Program  7-21. For convenience, we have reproduced the code for you below. Modify this function as follows:
change its type  to int 
change its name  to countMATCHES
make it return the number of corresponding parallel elements  that are equal

I have this code here:

```
int countMatches(int custPIN[], int databasePIN[], int size) {
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        if (custPIN[index] == databasePIN[index])
            return index;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Where exactly am I failing to do? Is it that I am infinitely stuck in this loop or is it something else?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: how you are calling this function ?

Answer (score 1):

As per description your code should be like below :

```
int countMatches(int custPIN[], int databasePIN[], int size) 
{
    int counter =0;
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        if (custPIN[index] == databasePIN[index])
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in the first line of the function you want to initialise a new counter variable to 0, and then, if the customer and database pins match, you increment it.
In the end, instead of returning the size, perhaps you want to return the counter, which now has been incremented for each matching character.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function trying  return more than once. If condition is true then you will return index but also will trying to return the size (which is not possible) where if its false then it will only return size 
Change the code as follows :

```
int countMatches(int custPIN[], int databasePIN[], int size) {
int e;

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++){ 
if (custPIN[index] == databasePIN[index]) { 
e++;
}
} 
if(e!=0)
return e; 
}
```

Hope this will help you.